# Visibility of Objects and its members throughout my project

Tags: java, visibility

i am fairly new to programming and i have a hard time to understand from where exactly i can access objects / methods.

I have a class

```
public class ShippingLine {

    ArrayList<Ship> shipList;
    ArrayList<Port> portList;
    String fileName;
    ContainerHandler containerHandler;

    public ShippingLine() {

        this.shipList = new ArrayList<Ship>();
        this.portList = new ArrayList<Port>();
        this.fileName = "container.csv";
        this.containerHandler = new ContainerHandler();

    }
public ArrayList<Ship> getShipList() {
    return this.shipList;
}


}
```

and in main i created a new ShippingLine() object shippingLine.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ShippingLine shippingLine = new ShippingLine();
```

i am now trying to access the ArrayList shipList in the object shippingList from following class method distributeContainers()

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContainerHandler {

    ArrayList<String[]> dataArr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    ArrayList<Container> containerArr = new ArrayList<Container>();
    String[] csvLine;
    String fileName;

    public void readContainerFile(String fileName) {


        this.fileName = fileName;
        try {

            File containerFile = new File(fileName);

            Scanner containerScanner = new Scanner(containerFile);

            int i = 0;
            while (containerScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                dataArr.add(
                        ("container " + i + ";" + containerScanner.nextLine() + ";" + IdHandler.getId()).split(";"));
                i++;

            }

            containerScanner.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < dataArr.size(); i++) {

            containerArr.add(new Container(dataArr.get(i)[1], dataArr.get(i)[2], Integer.parseInt(dataArr.get(i)[3]),
                    dataArr.get(i)[5]));

        }

    }

    public void distributeContainers() {

        for(Container container : containerArr ){

        }

    }

}
```

I don't understand why i can't access it from the other class in the same package. Is it a problem that one is an object inside an object and the other is not?  Can somebody help me with that ? I only started about a month ago.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods can only be accessed via an instance. Since ContainerHandler has no ShippingLane instance it cannot access any of ShippingLane's instance methods and/or instance fields

It looks like ContainerHandler is going to create some data that ShippingLane needs to hold onto. Rather than giving ContainerHandler a ShippingLane instance have ShippingLane tell ContainerHandler to create and return the data to ShippingLane and ShippingLane can put it in its shiplist. This way ContainerHandler does not need to know anything about a ShippingLane and it will also keep ShippingLane details encapsulated.

Comment: thanks for the answer. does that mean that the instance i created in main() is only visible to main()?

Comment: Since main has a reference to an instance of ShippingLine called "shippingLine" AND ShippingLine.getShipList() has a public access modifier then main, or any class with a ShippingLine instance reference, can do "nameOfShippingLineInstanceReference.getShipList()". So the ShippingLine instance reference called "shippingLine" is only visible to main since main is the only one with a reference("shippingLine") to the ShippingLine instance.

Comment: Also having a strong understanding of reference type vs object type and where each reside in memory will help out a lot for these situations. "ShippingLine shippingLine = new ShippingLine()" means "create a reference type variable of type ShippingLine(in stack memory) and assign to this variable a reference to the created instance/object of type ShippingLine(heap memory). The reference type variable is what gives other classes and instances access to that variables underlying object. Only Reference types and primitives are what are sent and returned from methods never objects/instances.